# How to combine SUMIF with another IF argument in excel for a date range?

Tags: excel

I needed to combine 'total orders' from another tab by customer ID for each one of the customers, for which I used SUMIF function and it worked.
The function that worked:

```
=SUMIF(Orderssheet!$B$2:$B$46,A3,Orderssheet!$E$2:$E$46)
```

For another column, I need to combine 'total orders' in the months of Jan, Feb and March.

How do I do that?
I thought that I needed to add the IF argument (with the dates) to the SUMIF and wrote this:

```
=SUMIF(Orderssheet!$B$2:$B$46,A3,Orderssheet!$E$2:$E$46),IF(Orderssheet!$B$2:$B$46,A3,">"&J19,Orderssheet!$E$2:$E$46,"<="&I19)

J19= 1/1/2016
I19= 3/1/2016
```

I get a value error...

Please help!

Comment: you probably are looking for [`SUMIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) which allows to use multiple criteria... something like `=SUMIFS(Orderssheet!$E$2:$E$46,Orderssheet!$B$2:$B$46,A3,Orderssheet!$E$2:$E$46,">"&J19,Orderssheet!$E$2:$E$46,"<="&I19)`

Answer (score -1):

Try using SUMIFS. Here is the syntax:

```
SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)
```

[more information here](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)